# В чем отличие двух книг по Java?

Tags: java, книги

Здравствуйте!
Решил начать изучать Java.
Мой выбор пал на книгу:
Java. Библиотека профессионала. Том 1. Основы, Кей Хорстманн.
10-е издание.

В процессе поиска в магазинах наткнулся и на такую книгу:
Java 2. Библиотека профессионала. Том 1. Основы, Кей Хорстманн, Гари Корнелл.
8-е издание.

В описании книг вот что написано:
Java - ... обновлено с учётом версии SE8.
Java 2 - ... обновлено с учётом версии SE6.

Вопрос: чем отличаются эти две книги? Книга по Java более актуальна, чем по Java 2?

Comment: [Обращайте внимание на описания меток](https://i.imgur.com/k72jjIW.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо оригинал книги был очень давно написан, поскольку

Java 2 (устаревшее название) = Java 1.2

SE8 (Standard Edition) = Java 1.8

Поскольку в изменениях версий в Java присутствует обратная совместимость, издатели дополняют старые книги материалом по изменениям с последних версий.

Так исторически сложилось, что были различные форматы представления версий релизов:

- JDK 1.0  1996
- JDK 1.1  1997
- J2SE 1.2 1998
- J2SE 1.3 2000
- J2SE 1.4 2002
- J2SE 5.0 2004
- Java SE 6    2006
- Java SE 7    2011
- Java SE 8    2014